# I can't detect all the blobs in the photo with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, detection

I'm trying to detect all the blobs in the given photos using opencv [this is the image I'm trying to process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXATd.png)

And this is my code

```
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
img = cv2.imread('bja_arka.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
# frame= cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
median = cv2.medianBlur(img, 1)
bilateral_blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(median, 1, 1, 3)

gaus = cv2.GaussianBlur(bilateral_blur, (1, 1), 1)
eroded = cv2.erode(gaus, (-1, -1), iterations = 2)
im_th= cv2.medianBlur(eroded, 5)

params.minThreshold = 160
params.maxThreshold = 230


params.filterByColor = True
params.blobColor = 0
params.filterByArea = True

params.minArea = 25



params.filterByCircularity = True

params.minCircularity = 0.01


params.filterByConvexity = True

params.minConvexity = 0.01


params.filterByInertia = True

params.minInertiaRatio = 0.1


if cv2.__version__.startswith('2.'):
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)
else:
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)


keypoints = detector.detect(im_th)


print(len(keypoints))


imgKeyPoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im_th, keypoints, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))

fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("Original")

fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(imgKeyPoints)
plt.axis('off')
plt.title("Holes Detected")

plt.show()
# Display found keypoints
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have tried doing it with contours and simple blob detector still could not increase the succession rate. How can I improve this code to detect all the blobs?
This is my input image [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl04Z.jpg) if someone wants to try. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Its up to parameters you defined: minarea, minCircularity etc. By playing with the parameters you ll be able to detect all the holes. It would be better to share input image with us so people may try to help you by themselves

Comment: I just edited the question with the necessary info Thank you!

Comment: As Yunus said it's all about the parameters. Here's some suggestions: use the I layer from HSI color space, plot the output of each filter you use at the beginning of the code to make sure they're not making the holes disappear, play with BlobeDetector parameters. But if you want this process to work with other similar images, it's silly to change the parameters for each of them! I think in that case you should use some sort of network and learning method to set the parameters for you!